# Pass authentication information as cookie or in header to external url when using it with MediaElement Source property in WPF

Tags: authentication, video-streaming, mediaelement, httpcontext

I am developing a wpf client which has to play a video from an external url. The server running behind the url is also managed by me. Now to protect the content and make it available only to the my wpf app, I was planning to use an authentication token which the wpf client has to pass to the server when it has to access and play the content. I am using `MediaElement` to play the video. I set `MediaElement.Source` to url of the video.

I thought I could pass the authentication token as cookie by setting `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);`

But for this to work, I need access to the HttpContext of the mediaElement which I dont have. So how can I ensure security of my video?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to include the credentials in the CGI params part of the URL used to request the video, or even in the URI itself if you have the ability to parse it out of the URI in your server.

I know this seems less secure, but because the URL will never be seen by the user since this is all loaded under the covers through WPF, they would never see the URL unless they are snooping with a network tool like Wireshark - in which case they will be able to sniff out your cookie as well. If you use HTTPS then both security issues are a moot point.